# How to search in a Set (using a Comparator)

Tags: java, collections, sorting, set, comparator

I want to search in a Set without iterating manually over the elments but there does not seem to be a method to do Collections.search(myset, target, new ComparatorThing()). Am I not seeing something?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

- I am searching for another field than the natural order of the elements.
- As a manual workaround I used the following static method. Should okay, since you can't make any assumtions about the other using a custom field in the comparator anyways.

```
public static  T search(final Set set, final T searchEntry, final Comparator comparator) {
    for (final T entry : set) {
        if (comparator.compare(entry, searchEntry) == 0) {
            return entry;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://commons.apache.org/collections/ which provides for example: `public static java.util.Set SetUtils.predicatedSet(set, predicate)`

Comment: Thanks, that would help. One should use commons collections more often but somehow I don't. Many of those things should be integrated into the std API imho.

Answer (score 1):

Need some more details here - are you attempting to search by an individual field in the Object contained in the `Set`? Or just find a certain element in the `Set`?

The idea of a `Set` itself, as the bare interface, has no idea of ordering - you would need to iterate over every element.

However if you restrict yourself to `SortedSet`, in which there is an ordering in place, you could possibly take advantage of the ordering, but since `Set`s do not allow for random access, you would still have to either iterate over every element or know more information about the collection beyond just that it's a `Set`.

Can you elaborate more on your algorithm and what you are trying to accomplish?

It is likely that a `Set` is not the ideal way to represent the data you want to "search" through.

Comment: Sorry, I am Searching for an individual field (Thats why I neet to be able to specify a comparator)

Actually I am using a TreeSet where the Elements, containing a string name and string value, are sorted by their Name (for display reasons - we are in the frontend) but now I have to search them by value.

I realized it now by manually iterating all entries and applying the (value) comparator.

Names and values are unique.

Comment: Is the comparator you want to use for the "search" the same that the `TreeSet` is constructed with (or if you aren't passing a `Comparator` to the `TreeSet` constructor, is it the same comparison logic used in your class the implements `Comparable`?) If yes, you might be able to take advantage of one of the `floor()` or `ceiling()` methods - these take advantage of the tree structure in searching for a node.

Comment: The comparator is a different one, this is the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `contains(Object o)`, from the `Collection` interface.  The Set interface extends Collection, so all sets are required to implement the Collection methods.

Bear in mind, if all you know of your object to search is that it is guaranteed to be a set, you have no guarantee there IS any way to search without iterating over each element, as this `contains()` method may or may not do depending on what type of set implementation you're actually using.

**References**

- [Collection#contains()](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29O)

Comment: Thanks, but the Problem with contains is, that I want to search for a different attribute than the one associated with it's equals / compareTo behavior.

Answer (score 0):

TreeSet has some methods that might be useful, for example `ceiling` to search for the next element greater or equals to the search key, `floor` to get the next lower element. Also headSet, tailSet and subSet to search for parts of a set lower, greater or between given limits.