# Efficient way of checking for a value present in an object, from an array of objects

Tags: java, dynamic

I have an array of objects. There is a getCountry() in the object. I want to set a flag when the getCountry() is equal to say 'XXX'.

As of know, I am doing,

```
boolean isXXX=false;
if(custAcctArray != null)
{
    for(int index=0;index<custAcctArray.length;index++)
    {
        if(custAcctArray[i].getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("XXX"))
        {
            isXXX=true;
        }
    }
}

if(isXXX)
{
    Do something about it....
}
```

I somehow don't like this logic when I assume the array is filled with some 100 or odd objects. Can someone throw or shed light at other ways of achieving the final output in an efficient way?
**What I want:** set a flag when **getCountry()**  == "**XXX**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
boolean isXXX=false;
if(custAcctArray != null)
{
    for(int index=0;index<custAcctArray.length;index++)
    {
        if(custAcctArray[i].getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase("XXX"))
        {
            isXXX=true;
            break;//<-------------you need to exit to be quick and true solution!!!!
        }
}
}

if(isXXX)
{
Do something about it....
}
```

Do you see the break; ? This exits the big loop as soon as possible. If you dont, the next iteration could set it to other value.

You can also use a "separate" array outside the object to access it quicker(1 less bounds checking)

A better way: when setting the country values, check that if "xxx" then set isXXX rightaway without needing to use a "check" algortihm :)

Comment: True. Always stop your loops once you've found, what you were looking for.

Comment: Did this make it a little quicker in overall ?

Comment: you can also use a "separate" array outside the object to access it quicker(1 less bounds checking)

Comment: break is fine. Did think about it. What did you mean by '"separate" array outside the object to access it quicker' ?? Didn't understand that.

Comment: you got an array of objects and you got an array of booleans parallel to objects. (1st array elemn is for 1st object in array, nth is for nth). Then no need to check object array bounds checking to lose time.

Comment: But you are wasting the memory for array of booleans just to avoid a check logic right ? Isn't that inefficient ?

Comment: Yes this is for desperate times. Speed vs size

Comment: No need for an array of booleans. If you can put this logic into the place where the array is initialized and use there a flag then it'll be the most efficient implementation as for me. `boolean found = false; for (...) { /* Array initialization. */ if (object.getCountry().equals("XXX") found = true; })` If you cannot do that, then you cannot use an array of booleans either.

Comment: But your "map" soultion is "dont invent the wheel again" +1 for that.

Comment: But let us dont forget that primitives are a little faster for now

Comment: There is one pitfall in using a map, and it is, that you won't be able to put the same key twice (it'll be overwritten). If you need objects which have the same key (same country), you probably better think about that `boolean` flag.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use a map instead of an array. The map should map from country to object. Then you will check whether the key exist in the map.

Another idea from the top of my head is to override the `toString()` method of that class and use `Arrays.toString(custAcctArray).contains("XXX")` (or maybe more reliable search using regexp). But it looks like a workaround. (This one is rather bad idea. Think about that as a tricky way to get rid of the loop in your code.)

Edit: To summarize my thoughts. Instead of a map, I think you should use a boolean flag (see my comment) if you know the value "XXX" when initializing the array or use a parallel set of country values. Use HashSet (efficiency O(1)), in this case you have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in your class. TreeSet is less efficient (O(log(n))) and still, here you use comparator or implement the interface `Comparable` in your class.

Edit: However, in this case we have `String` objects, so no need to implement anything (`hashCode()`, `equals()` and `compareTo()` are implemented there).

Comment: Do you really think that making a string of all collection elements and searching pattern in it is a faster way?

Comment: No. I didn't put enough thought into it. Now I realized it will be slower. It'll just remove the loop from the code, but will add several ones into the actual bytecode. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: +1 for a Map solution.  Those are really handy, and perfect in scenarios like this.

Comment: Infact a search in map is equal to for loops itself and if's (internal implementation). Is this search in Map faster than the logic written in the question ? If yes, then Maps are efficient.

Comment: The efficiency depends on a map implementation. The keys are stored in a set so the efficiency of look-up is the efficiency of look-up in a set. Probably the most common set is the `HashSet` and it's look-up efficiency is O(1) (constant) (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363626/how-to-search-in-a-set-using-a-comparator), but for that you need to write a good hash code implementation for your object. I'd suggest `country.hashCode()`.

Comment: Even a `TreeSet` is O(log n), which is faster than the O(n) you'll get from an array/list search.